# Can a Jewish man hold a woman's hand

Tags: halacha

Can a Jewish man hold a Jewish woman's hand or any woman's hand? If it's not allowed what's the violation? Can this man kiss a woman? Why not? Dioraisa issurim or medirabanan assurim? Which ones? Why?